# Should the name of a mythological creature be capitalized?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, grammar

The name of the mythological creature in my novel is "manananggal". When I'm referring to it, should I capitalize what it is?

Comment: The key concept here is the [proper noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun).

Comment: The answer to this question is yes because it lacks proper pluralization. manananggal**s** - you can't make up a word and expect to have people assume it's a non-count noun....

Comment: I think it's Filipino for 'unbelievers'. Is that deliberated?

Comment: @Mazura pluralisation has nothing to do with capitalisation.  Take for example "James" - "James'" see how it was pluralised?  eg - "James' stand up"  (an alternative spelling is James's).  As stated by David; proper nouns get capitalised, words starting a sentence also;  the rest do not.

Comment: Actually, it has nothing to do with capitalization, pluralization, or proper nouns. The problem is the word *creature*, which needs to be either *species* or *being* (or proceeded by the words *type of*); the answers to which are a *no* and a *yes* (and a *no*), respectively.

Answer (score 31):

### Yes, if it's the Grinch

A unique creature, which is *the* Manananggal (effectively THAT creature's name), should be capitalized.

### No, if it's a fairy

Even if your creature is rare, if you are likely to ever refer to it as *a* manananggal (a member of a group or species), then don't capitalize it.

Comment: Note that "the" isn't the indication. For example, I don't call you _the_ Jedediah but it's still your given name (well, chosen username, but you get my point). However, it would be correct to say that when "_a_ Manananggal" doesn't make sense, then it suggests that Manananggal is a given name and thus chould be capitalized.

Comment: On the other hand, there are many people called John, and there are situations when it makes perfect sense to say “a John”, yet “John” still is a proper name to be capitalized. And back to mythical creatures, if there is only one dragon, it would make sense to call it “the dragon” but you wouldn't capitalize “dragon” anyway.

Comment: Yes, the rule isn't perfect. What I'm trying to give a rough rule for, say, "a devil" versus "the Devil".  And English isn't even perfectly consistent on this, since in the King James Version of the bible, (or is it the Bible?), in Revelation 12, Satan is called "the Devil" and "the dragon".  Apparently, in the NIV, he's called "the Dragon".  The "the" rule is good but not perfect for title-names.  It doesn't apply to common names.

Comment: @celtschk The choice of "a John" is itself a bit of a special case, since that also refers to something else, besides just "one of many people with the name John".

Comment: @JMac good point. For that _other_  use of a John, would you still capitalize it?

Comment: @ale10ander Apparently not.  It's a regular noun, just like "john" in the sense of a British toilet.

Comment: @ale10ander that's *American* toilet - Brits don't call the toilet "john"

Comment: @ChrisB Correct, I was getting it confused with another of the 20 synonyms for toilet on the page I was looking at.

Answer (score 8):

Mythological creatures, or creatures you've invented, don't need to be capitalised, just like real-life animals. There's no grammatical difference between "a dog", "an orc", "a dragon" and "a manananggal".

To cite a famous example,

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit. (J.R.R Tolkien, *The Hobbit*, chapter 1 - An Unexpected Party)

Comment: It's a toss up whether your answer is correct or not, as "mythological creature" can (possibly) imply that only one exists, at which point their name is considered a given name and thus capitalized. For example: Bigfoot is a specific creature and thus capitalized, whereas yeti are considered a species and thus not capitalized.

Comment: @Flater Say there is only one fossil having given characteristics. Even though it's unique, biologists would give name to it as species and it is not to be capitalized.

Comment: @rus9384: Because every animal ever encountered has relied on procreation, which inherently means there is more than one animal of that species. The _fossil_ may be given a name, even _the particular creature_ to which the fossil belongs. Those are both given names referring to a unique entity. But the name of the _species_ is not a given name, not unique, and thus not capitalized. This is also well beyond the scope of the asked question.

Comment: @rus9384 here's an example of a fossil with a name: Ötzi, aka the Iceman etc: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ötzi

Comment: @ANeves I know fossils can be named proper nouns, but in my example I meant that it would be the only (yet discovered) fossil of given species.

Comment: @ANeves Otzi is no different from Lucy the Australopithecus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_(Australopithecus)). It's a personal name, given by scientists to a find. Personal names get capitalised. Species don't.

Comment: There are plenty of mythological creatures who are individuals with specific names, e.g. Medusa would be capitalised. It is not clear from from the original question whether "manananggal" is a species or an individual.

Comment: @Galastel taxonomic species names (like Australopithecus afarensis) are capitalized, however.

Comment: @SeanBurton Medusa is her given name though, she is a gorgon

Comment: @SeanBurton you are bringing up a very interesting example. Everybody capitalizes Medusa, but should Gorgon also be capitalized? My gut feeling is that i have more frequently seen it capitalized than not, although, by strict rule application, it shouldn't. Between gorgon Medusa and Gorgon Medusa, the first looks somehow strnage.

Comment: @rumtscho I had to look it up, and apparently when talking about the three Gorgon sisters, gorgon should be capitalized. Otherwise not. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gorgon

Comment: @eirikdaude The second use in MW is irrelevant, that's a metaphorical use in everyday language, and does not denote a monster in the sense of the question. The first one is interesting though. Why is a Gorgon capitalized and a titan is not? Yes the three are "one of a kind" in the sense of it being like a family name, but the titans are also "one of a kind", there are only 12 of them.

Answer (score 7):

### Do not capitalize the name of a species

> There are hobbits, dwarves, dragons, horses, dogs, unicorns, cats, and so on.

### Capitalize the personal name of an individual

> They saw Peter, the human being.
> They saw Capper, the dog.
> They saw Smaug, the dragon.

Smaug is the *personal name* of this dragon. Other dragons have other names.

Note that while there may be more than one Peter (and potentially more than one dragon named Smaug), there is no species of peters (or smaugs). The same name can be given to different individuals (of different species: Peter the dog, Peter the dragon), but that still doesn't make them members of their own species, nor Peter a class name. They are all Peters, but not peters.

### Capitalize the species names of unique beings

> The Grinch.

Grinch is not the personal name of this creature, it is the name of its species. But there is (or appears to be) only one of its kind, which makes its species name *like* a personal name in that it denotes a single unique individual. When I say "dragon" you don't know which one I speak of, but when I say "Grinch" you know which one I mean because there is only one of them, which makes "Grinch" function like a personal name.

Now you could say that the Grinch is a fictional character, invented by a writer of literature, and that its author may have chosen to capitalize this word on a whim. But there are examples from the real world that show the same difference in capitalization between the name of a mythological species and the name of a unique mythological being, such as *[banshee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee)* and *[Cailleach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cailleach)*. There are many banshees. It is the name of a species and is therefore not capitalized. But there is only one Cailleach. Yet Cailleach is not the personal name of this being, but a description: *cailleach* means "old woman" in Irish, just as *banshee* means "fairy woman". They are both species names, their difference is that Cailleach is a species with only one member, so she becomes *the Cailleach*, just like the Grinch.

---

As David Richerby has pointed out in a comment, "Grinch" and "Peter" are [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun), while "dragon" is not.

To summarize:

1. If there are **many** manananggals, **don't** capitalize the species name.
2. If there is only **one** Manananggal, **capitalize** its species or personal name.

Comment: Members of a particular organization, nation, or tribe which are identified with the name of that entity (e.g. a Mason, an Americal, or a Seminole) are also capitalized, even when used to refer to one of many members.  If there were a Society of Grinches, it would have been proper to capitalize the reference to the Grinch in the story, even if there were many other Grinches.